# How to set paragraph width as the width of the longest line

Tags: plain-tex

I have a paragraph with several lines ended using `\break`. I would like to set the width of the whole paragraph to the width of the longest line. How to achieve this?

I have a macro like this where I early changed `\\` into `\break`, I was recommended to use `\haling` and `\cr` but I can't see how to integrate it.

```
\everypar={\setbox0=\lastbox\endgraf\vbox\bgroup\everypar={\vrule height12pt width0pt}}
\def\par{\ifhmode\endgraf\egroup\fi}
\def\\{\unskip\break}
\rightskip=0pt plus 1fil\parindent=0pt #2\par
\everypar={}
```

This does not work:

```
\everypar={\setbox0=\lastbox\endgraf\vbox\bgroup\everypar={\vrule height12pt width0pt}}
\def\par{\ifhmode\endgraf\egroup\fi}
\def\\{\cr}
\rightskip=0pt plus 1fil\parindent=0pt \haling{#2}\par
\everypar={}
```

Comment: Can you post a full example, including the paragraph you're trying to typeset? In your code sample you have "haling" instead of "halign".

Answer (score 2):

TeX has the `\halign` primitive for this (this question is tagged “plain-tex”, isn’t it?).  Instead of `\break` you have to use `\cr`; a little drawback is that you have to request the paragraph indentation explicitly (with `\indent`) if you want it:

```
\halign{#\cr
  \indent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\cr
  Curabitur massa turpis, semper quis fringilla ut, viverra nec risus.\cr
  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique\cr
  senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.\cr
}

More text that is set at the normal text width, with line breaks chosen by 
\TeX's line breaking algorithm.  For example, a line break should have occurred 
at the beginning of this sentence.

\bye
```

Output:

[image: Output of the code]

Of course, it is easy to define “syntactic sugar” to make this more user-friendly.  Let me repeat that `\halign` is a *primitive* command of TeX, so it is *much* more efficient than any macro-based solution.
Moreover, it is worth remarking that `\halign` contributes the individual lines of the “‘Lorem ipsum…’ paragraph” to the main vertical list (as it happens with normal paragraphs), entailing that page breaks are allowed in the usual way; also the interline glue is administered as it normally is.

Comment: This seems that it could solve all of my problems, I am just not sure how to integrate it with my complicated macro.

Basically, I have a macro in which I was replacing \\ with \break, edited the question.

Comment: I am getting: Incompatible list can't be unboxed after I encapsulated my text in \halign and replaced \break with \cr.

Comment: @AlexanderWeps: I cannot offer any suggestion on how to integrate `\halign` into your “complicated macro” unless you show us this macro and you intend to use it.  More generally, it is not at all clear, from your question, what you are trying to achieve: could you explain it in detail, maybe with the help of a hand-made drawing?

Answer (score 1):

You could split everything at `\break`, typeset each line at natural width to determine the longest and then against typeset at maximum width.

```
\newdimen\maxwidth
\newbox\linebox

\def\adjustlines#1{%
  \foreachline\measure#1\break\break\endforeachline
  \ifdim\maxwidth>\hsize
    \vbox{#1}
  \else
    \vbox{\foreachline\adjust#1\break\break\endforeachline}
  \fi
}

\def\measure#1{%
  \setbox\linebox=\hbox{#1}
  \ifdim\wd\linebox>\maxwidth
    \maxwidth=\wd\linebox
  \fi}

\def\adjust#1{\hbox to \maxwidth{#1}}

\def\foreachline#1#2\break#3\endforeachline{%
  #1{#2}%
  \ifx#3\break\else
  \foreachline#1#3\endforeachline
  \fi
}

\def\endforeachline{}

\adjustlines{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.\break
  Curabitur massa turpis, semper quis fringilla ut, viverra nec risus.\break
  Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique\break
  senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.\break
}

\bye
```

[image]

If the longest line is longer than `\hsize`

[image]

Comment: This work best so far, but does not handle paragraphs.

Comment: @AlexanderWeps Can you be a bit more specific?  What do you mean with “it does not handle paragraphs”?

Comment: Just put \par or two new lines inside \adjustlines.